# Why doesn't the string match the root?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

From Reading 17 of [6.005 — Software Construction](http://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa15/classes/17-regex-grammars/):

> Exercise Reading a Grammar 4:
>
> Which strings match the root nonterminal of this grammar?
>
> ```
> root   ::= (A B)+
> A      ::= [Aa]
> B      ::= [Bb]
> ```
>
> 1. `aaaBBB`
> 2. `abababab`
> 3. `aBAbabAB`
> 4. `AbAbAbA`
>
> Answer: 2 and 3

So far so good.

> Exercise Reading a Grammar 3:
>
> Which strings match the root nonterminal of this grammar?
>
> ```
> root    ::= integer ('-' integer)+
> integer ::= [0-9]+
> ```
>
> 1. `617`
> 2. `617-253`
> 3. `617-253-1000`
> 4. `---`
> 5. `integer-integer-integer`
> 6. `5--5`
> 7. `3-6-293-1`
>
> Answer: 2, 3, and 7

In the last question, why doesn't `integer-integer-integer` match the root if it can be our first step, i.e.

`root` ⇒ `integer-integer-integer`

Sure, it would not be the end of the story (i.e. it would contain some non-terminals) but neither was `aBAbabAB` in the question above and yet it was accepted as a string that matched the root.

Many thanks!

Comment: `integer` is a non-terminal, whereas a string is composed of terminals like the digits and the dash. I agree that this is not the definition of *string* used in the preceding exercise.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: you mean that the answer to the preceding exercise has a typo, i.e. that it should be only `abababab` and not `aBAbabAB` since the later isn't even a string?

Comment: The two answers are inconsistent. Which is correct depends on the definition of *string*.

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/).

Comment: And here we see why many authors choose to have $T \cap N = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

In the text, they seem to suggest that there is a way of quoting characters so that they can be used as terminals even if they have the visible form as a non-terminal. One common quoting form is quotes (`'B'`) which is illustrated.

Character classes (`[bB]`) are another quoting form. The `B` in that character class cannot be a non-terminal because it is precisely a *character*. So the non-terminal `B`, although it looks very similar, is distinct, and the `B`s in the strings are characters, necessary by the definition of string they are using.